# Best practices for handling asynchronous tasks in JavaFX 2?

Tags: javafx, javafx-2

Start developing a JavaFX App I got some questions about handling concurreny. I know the concurrency tools from JavaFX (`Service`, `Task`, `Timeline`), but I have no clue what´s the best apporach to use them in a real JavaFX application.

I am using FXML and I would like to start a asychronous, recurring task. It´s the best way to create the `Service` in my `Main` application or in the `Controller` classes? Since the `Service` shall update the UI, I still need a reference to a controller.

Does anyone has some best practices how to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Knut said, you could just implement your recurrent task in your controller.

Still there is room for improvement, you can define a ServiceFactory for instance which can be useful as you probably want to add code on each service you create to log what is going on this Thread / or add a default fault handler on the service for instance.

If you use an IOC framework like Spring, it will enable you to define easily a ThreadPool to spawn your threads for your services with specified parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice would probably be to treat a `controller` as a way to access the components declared in the FXML file and nothing but that, i.e. just a part of the UI definition without any domain logic. There's no good reason why you couldn't code a service within the same class, but there's probably no good reason *for* it either.